# Why does the LED turn off when I try to measure current?

Tags: led, current, current-measurement, multimeter

I have the following circuit:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fv6UlG.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I'm trying to measure the current in it, which should be

\$\frac{\text{5V}}{\text{220}\Omega} \approx 22 \text{mA}\$

The problem is that, when I put my multimeter in, the current is measured correctly, but the LED turns off.

[Click here](https://youtu.be/trvaqhnrOsA) to see what I mean.

Why does the LED turns off?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *Why does the LED turns off?*

The LED needs about 2 volts across it before fully illuminating. But, if the voltage across it drops below around 1.8 volts, it'll not illuminate at all. And, it'll drop low when measuring current (your way) because your meter has a low measurement impedance close to 0 Ω.

With your ammeter in parallel with the LED you collapse the voltage across the LED to a few millivolts and the LED fails to illuminate. The full 5 volts appears across the 220 Ω resistor and you incorrectly infer that the current in the LED is 22 mA. That's what flows through your meter.

The actual LED current (when operating without the ammeter shorting it out) will be about 14 mA because the LED drops about 2 volts leaving about 3 volts across the 220 Ω resistor hence, 3/220 = 14 mA.

If you want to measure current without interrupting current flow into the LED, measure the voltage across the 220 Ω resistor and compute LED current that way. Or, put your ammeter in series with the LED or resistor.

Comment: By putting the multimeter in series, it measures 0 .... why?

Comment: I have no idea why. Maybe you switched to a voltage measurement? Maybe you switched to an AC measurement? Maybe you used the leads in the wrong sockets of the meter. You'll have to figure that out yourself. I'm just answering you main question @robertspierre

Comment: I did it. I was not putting it in series, but in parallel with a short circuit. Thank you very much! Your answer is very clear and detailed, I'm accepting it. Thanks!

Comment: @robertspierre An important safety point for multimeters: when you've finished using it, if you're going to leave them connected, make sure the probes are in the sockets for voltage measurement.